# psycopg2 connects from Windows, but not Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ubuntu, psycopg2

My Postgres database only accepts requests from localhost. Requests from a remote computer rely on SSH tunnel.

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('my.db.ip.address', 22),
        ssh_username='ssh_user_name',
        ssh_private_key='id_rsa.pem',
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5432)) as server:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="my_db", port=server.local_bind_port, user=id, password=pwd)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    sql = "select t.id from public.my_table t"
```

This code works from Windows machine. On Ubuntu it fails with

```
  File "/home/me/projects/compliance/response_generator.py", line 22, in get_rows
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="my_db", port=server.local_bind_port, user=id,password=pwd)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.38945" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

What could be the reason and how to fix it?

----Update-----

```
tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
  ('my.db.ip.address', 22),
  ssh_username='ssh_user_name',
  ssh_private_key='exdtras.dat',
  remote_bind_address=('localhost', 5432),
  local_bind_address=('localhost',6543), # could be any available port
```

Returns     `raise ValueError('No password or public key available!') ValueError: No password or public key available!`

Any idea why this code works on Windows, but fails on Ubuntu?

Comment: Here is an example [SSHTunnelForwarder Postgres](https://gist.github.com/deehzee/53c8708417312e5deb32c58b73dca7a5).

Comment: Failed. See the update

Comment: Why did you change to: `ssh_private_key='exdtras.dat',`? Can you do a `SSH` connection to the remote host from the command line?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, I can connect to the machine with ssh as ssh_user_name@ip. However, the `ssh_user_name` is not a sudoer and cannot run `psql`

Comment: You don't need to use `sudo` to run `psql` so I am not following?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver psql: error: FATAL:  role "ssh_user_name" does not exist. I don't have root password and I cannot do `sudo -u postgres createuser <local username>`

Comment: ` FATAL: role "ssh_user_name"` just means that user is not a database user. You can still do `psql -d postgres -U <db_user>` where `<db_user> ` is a user name that exists in the database, say `postgres`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver `psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user <some_sql_user_id>`  This still does not answer the question. How to adapt Python code that is working on Windows, but is failing on Ubuntu.